# GPS and NETWORK Providers return null always

Tags: android, location

My app keeps crashing when I try to send the location to the server.

My main activity is--

```
                  package com.ambujkathotiya.swachhb.activity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ambujkathotiya.swachhb.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     LocationListener {

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

String longi;
String lat;
LocationManager locationManager;


// Camera activity request codes
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Main code
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy tp = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
    }

    // Changing action bar background color
    // These two lines are not needed


    ImageButton btnCapturePicture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);


    /**
     * Capture image button click event
     */
    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // capture picture
            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netinfo = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnected()) {
                // Internet Connection is present
                //Check if location services is switched on or not

                LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                if (locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    //Location services enabled
                    //Call the camera
                    captureImage();
                } else {
                    //Location services not enabled
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            } else {
                // Internet connection is not present
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! You need an internet connection to proceed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    });


    // Checking camera availability
    if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // will close the app if the device does't have camera
        finish();
    }
}

/**
 * Checking device has camera hardware or not
 * */
private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
    // this device has a camera
// no camera on this device
    return      getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
}

/**
 * Launching camera app to capture image
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}



/**
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}



/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // successfully captured the image
            // launching upload activity
            getLocation();
            Log.d(TAG, "hi" + lat);
            Log.d(TAG, "hello"+longi);
            launchUploadActivity(true);


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }

}

private void launchUploadActivity(boolean isImage){

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("filePath", fileUri.getPath());
    i.putExtra("isImage", isImage);
    i.putExtra("lat",lat);
    i.putExtra("longi",longi);
    startActivity(i);
}

/**
 * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
 * */

/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

public void getLocation()
{
    //Location code
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //If location manager returns not null,then save the lat and long
    if (locationManager != null) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,this);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                lat = Double.toString(latitude);
                longi = Double.toString(longitude);
            }
            else if(location1 != null){
                double latitude = location1.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location1.getLongitude();
                lat = Double.toString(latitude);
                longi = Double.toString(longitude);
            }
            else {
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            finish();
        }
        //Remove the request for location updates.
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    } else {

        finish();
    }
}

}
```

After this the app is sent to an activity where I have to upload the data to a server.As soon as I click the upload button,the app crashes saying there was a problem in doInBackground(). I tried showing location in log and it returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your location code is screwed up.  You call requestLocationUpdates, but you don't wait for it to call onLocationChanged-  you assume that its instant.  It isn't.  You then call getLastLocation, which will return null 90% of the time because it hasn't had a chance to actually launch the location code yet (location discovery takes time, even for network which is faster).  Rip it out, replace it with just calls to requestLocationUpdates, and wait for those to actually return a location-  don't just call getLastLocation afterwards.  In fact you're probably better off just forgetting that function exists.

Comment: I'm new to Android development actually. Can you kindly point it out where should I make the changes? Sorry for being stupid.